# How to receive response from an HTTPS site (PYTHON)

Tags: python, ssl, https

I would like to know how do I connect and receive a response from a website that uses HTTPS I believe I have to use ssl but I do not know how?

```
import socket


client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("www.netflix.com", 443))
client.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.netflix.com\r\n\r\n")
print client.recv(1024)
```

Comment: Handle TSL by yourself is not a good idea. use requests https://github.com/requests/requests

Comment: You do not seem to understand what HTTPS is in the first place. HTTPS is simply HTTP (which you attempt) over TLS instead of plain TCP (which you currently do). To create a TLS socket on top of a TCP socket use [ssl.wrap_socket](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#socket-creation) or similar and there are lots of information on how to use this.